# Why does attaching stop a process/thread in Linux?

Tags: linux, gdb, ptrace

I understand how single stepping and the `int 3` bytes are used to debug programs. In the first case, the tracer uses `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP` to be able to debug the program one instruction at a time. On x86, this means that the trap flag would be set while debugging. In the second case, `0xcc` bytes are inserted into the tracee's address space and whenever a SIGTRAP arises, control is passed back onto the tracer(debugger).

Now, when I attach to a program using the gdb debugger, the tracee is paused. What happens internally? Is a `0xcc` byte inserted? How exactly does the ptrace library pause the tracee's exection?

Answer (score 4):

`ptrace` is a system call, implemented by the kernel.  The kernel decides whether a process can execute at all.  When it is attached via `ptrace` in the ordinary way, it pauses execution -- presumably by setting a flag and never scheduling it, but I never looked that deep.

Note that newer versions of the Linux kernel include a `PTRACE_SEIZE` request, which can be used to attach to a process without stopping it.  The `ptrace` man page explains this a bit.